# 'The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.'?

Tags: c#, select, linq-to-entities

I'm using C# and asp.net.

I am trying to separate an email address during a SQL Select query located inside the rest of my C# code. My goal is to display a series of email addresses and each email address's domain names on a webpage. These emails are stored in a SQL database, and I am using a SQL Select query to access them. If someone's email is "john@gmail.com", then I want to display on a webpage "john@gmail.com" and "gmail.com." To accomplish this, I want to use the C# code Split('@')[1] to split the email address in order to just display the domain name of the email address.

However, the SQl Select query does not allow the use of the Split('@')[1] method, and I encounter the following error: 'The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.' I am not sure how to proceed.

Here is my code below:

```
        if (sortProperty != null)
        {
            groupMemberGrid.DataSource = groupMembers.Select(gm => new MemberData()
            {
                Email = gm.Person.Email,
                EmailDomain = gm.Person.Email.Split('@')[1]
            }).Distinct().Sort(sortProperty).ToList();
```

I've been banging my head against this for several hours with no idea how to proceed. This is the first time I have encountered this error.

Comment: LINQ in general supports any valid C# code, which is why your code compiles. Not all LINQ providers support all C# code though, which is why you're seeing a run time exception. At run time, your LINQ code is processed by whatever LINQ provider is appropriate in the context. If you're using Entity Framework then you're using the LINQ to Entities provider. That provider converts your C# code to SQL code, so not all C# code is supported. There is no mapping from that `String.Split` method to SQL. You should read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/database-functions).

Comment: In that linked page, the EF.Functions section is what should interest you first. There may be a dedicated function for splitting a string that you can use. I'm not sure exactly what's available and it depends on your database. If there isn't, probably the simplest option is to just get the data with the `EmailDomain` property empty and then use a loop to populate it after the fact.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions) is a list of function mappings for SQL Server. I don't see a method that will do a split but there is one to get the index of a character and another to get a substring based on index, so that is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, LINQ itself supports any valid C# code, so queries like this will compile. Individual LINQ providers, which are what get invoked at run time to actually perform the query, may not support certain types, members or code constructs.

If you're using Entity Framework then you're using the LINQ to Entities provider. It has to convert your query to SQL code to be executed on the database, so there are numerous examples of valid C# code that is not supported because it is too difficult to provide a translation that will work for every database. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/database-functions).

There is also a set of extensions that may or may not be implemented for specific databases. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions) are those mappings for EF Core and SQL Server. There is no single function that will mimic `string.Split` but there is one that will get the index of a character in a string and another that will get a substring based on index. Those two will do the job here.

Without having tested, I think that the following will do what you want, based on my reading of that documentation:

```cs
EmailDomain = gm.Person.Email.Substring(gm.Person.Email.IndexOf('@') + 1)
```